# Infimum and supremum of $\{x\in[-1,4]\mid\sin x>0\}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S=\{X\in[-1,4]\mid\sin(x)>0\}$. Which of the following is true?
>
> 1. $\inf(S)<0$,
>
>    $\sup(S)$ does not exist,
>
>    $\sup(S)=π$,
>
>    $\inf(S)=\dfracπ2$.

I was trying to get the infimum and supremum of the set, but I am not able solve it. Please help.

Comment: What do you know for the sine function on $[-1,4]$, is it bounded? What are the bounds? Try to look for the extrema  and the zeroes of the sine function to check at which $x\in[-1,4]$ they occur

Comment: sine function is always bounded between -1 and 1 and inf of sine in the given interval is 0 and i dont know the sup of sine in that interval

Comment: Draw a picture of $S$, that will do I think

Comment: Also, recall the statement of the Axiom of Completeness!

Answer (score -1):

Since $\sin(x)>0$, $x$ can take values only between 0 and $\pi$ as you can see in the graph of sine function. So the set $S = \{ x \in [-1,4] \mid \sin(x)>0 \}$ will be reduced to $S = \{ x \in (0,\pi) \mid \sin(x)>0 \}$. Note that $\sup(S)$ is not 4. Therefore, the correct answer is $\sup(S) = \pi$.